# only show lines with a pattern1 following a line with another pattern2

Tags: bash

I'm trying filter a dump from objump and I'm currently stuck on filtering some desired lines.

I have something like this right now ...

```
many lines with pattern1 I dont need
line I don't need with pattern1
line I don't need with pattern1
line with pattern1 I need because the NEXT LINE matches the pattern2
  line with pattern2
line with pattern1 I need because the NEXT LINE matches the pattern2
  line with pattern2
  line with pattern2
line I don't need with pattern1
line I don't need with pattern1
many lines with pattern1 I dont need
```

So the thing is, I need to delete every single line, including the lines with a pattern2, and **only keep the lines with pattern1* following a pattern2. I need to do this in a universal way. (I'm making a script).

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -n '/pattern1/{N; /\n.*pattern2/!{D;b};p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk should do what you want

```
 $ awk '/pattern1/{k=$0;next}/pattern2/&&k{print k};{k=0}' file
line with pattern1 I need because the NEXT LINE matches the pattern2
line with pattern1 I need because the NEXT LINE matches the pattern2
```

We store the lines that match `pattern1` in variable `k`, and skip the remaining commands

If a line matches `pattern2` and the variable `k` is not zero, then we print the stored line.

We set the variable back to zero if the line did not match  `pattern1`

Comment: thank you for swift answer..this is great except it shows me the lines that are UNDER the line with pattern2. I need the ones that are ABOVE

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the question. I will edit another answer in

Comment: @user2226306 I updated the answer. Please check if it works properly on your data